# Angular Chrome Extension Allowed In Chrome Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Are chrome extensions built using angular 7 allowed in the chrome webstore?

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think it may be disallowed?

Comment: Someone I know said that angular apps are not allowed. I didn't see anything after reading alot, so I figured I would ask the people who have published extensions.

Comment: I see no reason why any JavaScript framework would be disallowed. You got trolled, probably.